# Can you disable responsive layout for certain pages on WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive, siteorigin

I am using WordPress and SiteOrigin Page Builder to build my website. In the settings for SiteOrigin Page Builder, I can select to make the pages have a responsive layout or turn it off all together.

The thing is, I want most of pages to be responsive, but not all of them. I am wondering if there is a way to use custom css to make the particular pages I want to exclude non-responsive?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can target specific pages with css, by selecting elements based on the post or page id that is available on each page. Take a look at the source of a rendered page in your browser and look for a specific id relating to that post; use its naming convention to also target other pages. E.g #post-213. Using css, you can then change responsive widths to static widths. I.e. 100% to 1200px etc.